# Changing the Axes

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to know that how can I change my axes variables (I might be messy in explaining). For example, I have a system of 2 first-order odes with P(t) and $\psi(t)$ as their variables. The equations are like,
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=\frac{Pe^{-3t}}{a^{3}V},$$
$$\frac{\partial P }{\partial t}=-0.5a^{3}Ve^{3t}m^{2}Z\sin(\frac{2\psi(t)}{M}),$$
where M,m,Z,V and a are constants (random values).
I will give initial conditions (Random), and I want to plot 3d plot in which P, $\psi$, and t are included on the axes. I want to know how I can do that?
Can I do something like plot P on the y axis and $\psi$ on the x axis. If yes, then how can I do that?

Comment: Huh?!?  If you have a 3D plot with one axis labeled $\psi$ and another labeled $P$, what would you label the third (vertical) axis??  What, exactly, are you trying to plot?

Comment: I want to label third axes with time, t. Because there is an exponential term in the equations.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.  You want to plot *time* as a function of two physical variables??  Might your function (in principle) have two values?  So two "times" for values of $\psi$ and $\phi$?  Please find even one such graph anywhere on the internet that shows what you seek.  If you find none... well, it likely means you're confused about what you want.

Comment: No, I actually want to plot these two physical variables as a function of time in a 3d grid. Is that possible? Cause I have seen.

Comment: As I requested:  SHOW an example of what you've seen.  Post a link.  Otherwise I certainly cannot help you... and I strongly doubt others can either.

Comment: Let me simplify, if I just remove exponential term, can I plot a simple plot with P on y axis, and $\psi$ on x axis?

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Polymer-inflation-Hassan-Husain/e0b02662eaa7c459e7267e9d8117d44333158610/figure/1 in this figure, N is time.

Comment: But you wanted time to be *VERTICAL*---that time is a *function* of your other variables.  Your linked graph is a standard graph of two values always as a function of the *SINGLE* variable $t$ (or $N$)... very different.

Comment: Sorry David, I was confused before. I want to follow the same methodology of the shown figure, for my odes. And I cant figure out to do them.

Comment: And your equation involves $\psi$ but the argument in the $\sin$ function is $\phi$.  too confusing for me (or anyone) to help.

Comment: I have edited the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how proficient you are in Mathematica, since you haven't posted any code (which might lead into closing the question), so let me outline the main steps.

##### 1. Write the differential equations

```
eqs = {
   \[Psi]'[t] == P [t] Exp[-3 t]/(a^3 V),
   P'[t] == -0.5 a^3 V Exp[3 t] m^2 Z Sin[2 \[Psi][t]/M],
   \[Psi][0] == 1,
   P[0] == 1
};
```

Mind the initial conditions.

##### 2. Solve the system numerically

```
sol = NDSolve[  eqs /. {M -> .08, m -> 2, Z -> 5, V -> .0005, a -> 3}, 
   {\[Psi], P}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

I have chosen some random, sensible values for your parameters.

##### 3. Plot a parametric 3D curve

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t, \[Psi][t], P[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Psi]", "P"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think this is as far as I can help you given what you've told us.

Comment: I am sorry for not posting the code. I know how to solve odes (my work is related to it), numerically and plot the results. But I was confused in 3d plots. For example, in a phase portrait command, it is built-in to plot $\dot{\phi}$ vs $\phi$. I also wanted to know how I can plot $\dot{\phi}$ vs $\phi$ using the NDSolve and plot command. Thanks your plot helps.